# Edges of a graph

Tags: c

Consider we have a graph with n vertices (1<=n<=5000) and the vertices are named 0,1,2,...,n-1;each vertex is labeled with a number ai (means the vertex i is labeled ai) and we know that 1<=ai<=100000 (1<=i<=n).

The vertices u and v are connected if and only if |au-av|=1.
write the program that measures the number of this graph's edges.

Input: In the first line n is given and in the next n lines a0,a1,a2,...,a(n-1) must be given.

Output: The number of graph's edges.

I personally have written a code below that works correctly but I'm looking for a faster algorithm that doesn't check each two vertices.

For example if the time limit is 0.5 seconds this is not a good algorithm.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    long long int a[5000],n,i,j,edge=0;
    scanf("%lld",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%lld",&a[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=i+1;j<n;j++){
            if(a[i]-a[j]==1 || a[i]-a[j]==-1){
                edge=edge+1;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%lld",edge);
}
```

I have an idea that I think it can help the progress get faster but I don’t know how to write the code: I think if we can calculate that for a constant number k how many ai’s are equal to k and then put them in another array it can make the ptogress of checking faster,I mean for example if n=12 and the ai’s are 1, 2, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7 here we have one 1,one 2,two 4’s,three 5’s,one 6 and four 7’s and so these equal ai’s doesn’t need to be checked more than one time with other values.

Comment: (a) Why is `a` declared `a[100000]` when its indices are the vertex names, which range from 1 to 5000? (b) Do you know of something you could do to the array `a` to make it easier to find elements whose values are close together? (c) Alternatively, if you did have an array of 100,000 elements, is there something you could use it for that would make it easy to find vertex labels that are close together?

Comment: You could speed up the performance by representing the graph using adjacency lists.

Comment: Sorry for this, I now have editet the size of array a

Comment: @b.j: Now you have `a` declared `a[5000]`, which means it can be indexed with 0 to 4999. But the indices for it range from 1 to 5000. Additionally, you should think about my questions (b) and (c).

Comment: Yes I understand what you say but labeles are just definitions and the code above works.I mean we can name the vertices 0,1,...,n-1 and the lables will be a0,...,a(n-1) and no differences.

Comment: Maybe we can sort the elements of the array but I don’t know how it can help us to find a faster algorithm.

Comment: Sorting the labels gives you strong constraints to find values for `i` and `j` such that `abs(a[i]-a[j]) == 1`. Using these constraints, counting edges can be done in a single traversal of `a`. If you know about time complexity, the whole thing can be done in linear time instead of quadratic time (your algorithm).

Comment: @Nelfeal: Sorting requires O(n log n) time, so the whole thing cannot be done in O(n) time when sorting is used.

Comment: @b.j: Ah, I see your code uses 0 to 4999, while your question says 1-5000. You should take care that the specification of a problem matches the code, or vice-versa.

Comment: @b.j: You should address my questions (b) and (c). They are clues.

Comment: I added my own idea to the question that I think it can help the progress get faster

Comment: @EricPostpischil Sorting requires `O(n)` in this case (probably `~64n`) or `O(max(ai))`.

Comment: @Nelfeal: How do you figure? Sorting generally requires O(*n* log *n*) on average because there are *n*! possible rearrangements that might be required. If you are thinking of a radix sort on the values using a 100,000-element array, the time required is then on the order of the number of potential values (100,000 in this case), which is not *n*.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Counting sort would take `O(max(ai))` (the number of potential values). Radix sort takes `O(wn)` where `w` is the number of "digits", in some way.

Comment: this question is asking for a review of the code, so it should be moved to 'codereview'

Comment: @user3629249 I don't see why. Plenty of questions on SO are about finding a faster algorithm or lowering complexity.

Comment: @user3629249: No, it is not asking for a review of the code. It is an algorithm question, not a code question.

Comment: @Nelfeal: The number of potential values is not *n* or O(*n*), so O(the number of potential values) is not O(*n*).

Comment: @EricPostpischil I know, that's why I wrote `max(ai)` (assuming `min(ai) = 1`).

Comment: @Nelfeal: Earlier you wrote sorting requires O(*n*) in this case.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It does, using radix sort and assuming `w` is constant, which is the case for `long long int` values. It seems you are mixing up radix sort and counting sort.

Comment: @Nelfeal: As you wrote, radix sort is O(*wn*), where *w* is the key size. Assuming it is constant is cheating; the complexity is a function of *n* and something else, not O(*n*).

Comment: @EricPostpischil Right, for a moment there I forgot that `max(ai) > n` which makes `log(max(ai)) > log(n)`. It is cheating within the scope of the question. However, since complexity is mainly relevant as `n` grows, I'm still going to say that `w` is constant (17 for `1<=ai<=100000`) and that using a radix sort here is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally found a good algorithm.Thanks for your help.
Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
long long int a[100000],b[100002]={0},n,i,j,edge=0;
scanf("%lld",&n);
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    scanf("%lld",&a[i]);
    b[a[i]]++;
}
for(i=1;i<100002;i++){
    edge=edge+b[i]*b[i-1];
}
printf("%lld",edge);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If OP's code is indeed correct, then vertex labels *k* are not unique, and many different vertices can have the same label.

Let's say you have an array *n* of 100,002 unsigned integers, numbered from 0 to 100,001 inclusive, and each capable of representing values from 0 to 5,000. Initialize them all to zeroes.

When you add a vertex labeled *k*, increment unsigned integer *n*[*k*]. If *n*[*k*-1] + *n*[*k*+1] is nonzero, adding this vertex created that many new edges.

If you count how many edges you create, you have the result immediately after you add the last vertex.

---

If the vertex labels were unique, but there might be (erroneously) duplicate labels *k* that are to be ignored, then:

Let's say you have an array of 100,002 flags, numbered from 0 to 100,001 inclusive, and initialized to all clear.

Whenever you see vertex labeled *k*, check if flag *k* is already set. If it is, then this is a duplicate flag to be ignored.

Otherwise, set the flag, and examine flags *k*-1 and *k*+1. If one of them is set, you created one new edge; if both flags are set, you created two new edges. If both are clear, no new edges were created.

If you count how many edges you create, you have the result immediately after you add the last vertex.

Comment: It depends what the labels represent. OP mentions that the vertex indices are their "names". "Label" can mean "attached information", not necessarily unique.

Comment: @Nelfeal: I split this into two, depending on what the label represents.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Thanks for your help;could you please post the code by your idea?because I have trouble with writing the code.

Comment: @b.j: I verified the first description produces the same results as your code for the same input. Even with full error checking, the code is less than 25 lines. How about you try to write it on your own, using my description above? I am not going to post the solution, and risk you copy-pasting it and presenting as your own work, without even understanding how the code does what it does. I don't like that. I only like to help people *learn*.